# Dataframe.lookup and map combination resulting in column label error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe of around (1200, 10) of mostly string where I have to append a new column say 'Z' based an existing reference column say 'Y', whose values are 'A', 'B', 'C', or unknown (NaN or other), from this I need to select one of three corresponding columns in the df say 'D', 'E', 'F', or output NaN and append this value as column 'Z'. I currently have the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'T': {0: '.', 1: '.', 2: '.', 3: '.'}, 
                   'G': {0: '.', 1: '.', 2: '.', 3: '.'}, 
                   'D': {0: 4, 1: 1, 2: 5, 3: 3}, 
                   'E': {0: 6, 1: 2, 2: 7, 3: 2}, 
                   'F': {0: 8, 1: 3, 2: 9, 3: 1}, 
                   'K': {0: '.', 1: '.', 2: '.', 3:'.'}, 
                   'Y': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'B', 3: np.nan}})

d = {'A': 'D', 'B': 'E', 'C': 'F'}
df['Z'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.Y.map(d))
```

The issue is that lookup breaks down where Y is an unknown value. and in the specific code, Y.unique() turns up something like (A, B, C, NaN, nan). So I was wondering if there would be a way to use a lookup-esque method that outputs Z to NaN where Y is NaN or unknown outside of the the given dict?

```
    T   G   D   E   F   K   Y   Z
0   .   .   4   6   8   .   A   4.0
1   .   .   1   2   3   .   B   2.0
2   .   .   5   7   9   .   B   7.0
3   .   .   3   2   1   .   NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `stack` and `reindex` with zip for multiindexes:

```
df['Z'] = df.stack().reindex(zip(df.index, df.Y.map(d))).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   T  G  D  E  F  K    Y    Z
0  .  .  4  6  8  .    A    4
1  .  .  1  2  3  .    B    2
2  .  .  5  7  9  .    B    7
3  .  .  3  2  1  .  NaN  NaN
```

Details:

First, let's use `stack`, move the column header into the dataframe row index, creating a multiindex for the dataframe.  Where, level 0 is the original row index, and level 1 are the column headers.

Now, we can use `reindex` to filter down to only those indexes we need.  Multiindex are identified using tuples. (level0, level1) hence, we `zip` df.index and df.y.map(d) together creating the tuples used by reindex.

Lastly, we drop the level=1 of the multiindex creating a structure of the original index and assign a new column with those values.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace missing values by some helper value which not exist in `Y` column and add new helper column with same name by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for match these values:

```
df['Z'] = df.assign(tmp = np.nan).lookup(df.index, df.Y.map(d).fillna('tmp'))
print (df)
   T  G  D  E  F  K    Y    Z
0  .  .  4  6  8  .    A  4.0
1  .  .  1  2  3  .    B  2.0
2  .  .  5  7  9  .    B  7.0
3  .  .  3  2  1  .  NaN  NaN
```

Another solution:

```
df[np.nan] = np.nan
df['Z'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.Y.map(d))
df = df.drop(np.nan, axis=1)
print (df)
   T  G  D  E  F  K    Y    Z
0  .  .  4  6  8  .    A  4.0
1  .  .  1  2  3  .    B  2.0
2  .  .  5  7  9  .    B  7.0
3  .  .  3  2  1  .  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using `.values`

```
df['Z'] = df.values[df.index, df.columns.get_indexer_for(df.Y.map(d))]
df
Out[135]: 
   T  G  D  E  F  K    Y    Z
0  .  .  4  6  8  .    A    4
1  .  .  1  2  3  .    B    2
2  .  .  5  7  9  .    B    7
3  .  .  3  2  1  .  NaN  NaN
```